# jQuery File Upload - transparent background when editing/cropping

Tags: jquery, file, background, upload, crop

I have install jQuery File Upload to my site because I need a system that crop files before it is uploaded to my server.

But when I'm cropping the picture, if I zoom out the image, there is a transparent background behind the image.

[image]

Is there a way to "block" this zoom out? I can't let users send cropped images with transparent borders on the side.

Answer (score 0):

I found it on cropper.js docs:

zoomable: false